# css validator showing parse errors

Tags: css, media-queries, w3c-validation

I'm building my first ever site and teaching myself HTML and CSS. I ran my style sheet through W3C validator and got parse error messages for all my media queries, like the error below.

What am I doing wrong?

> Parse Error screen and (min-width: 938px) { .drop-nav li { padding:
>   58px; } }

Here is my CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 938px) {

    .drop-nav li {
        padding: 58px;
    }

}
```

Comment: I believe you are checking with `html` validator :) try `css` instead as you code is fine

Answer (score 1):

On the W3C validation page make sure the setting are set to CSS3.

Comment: Try this link foe the W3C validator. [CSS Validation Service](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)